# Should my CVDisplayLinkOutputCallback method be used to update as well as render an OpenGL scene

Tags: cocoa, appkit, nsopenglview

I have managed to set up an `NSOpenGLView` using `CVDisplayLinkSetOutputCallback` as a method to render a scene in my application. Everything appears to be working correctly and the callback method is firing at a pretty decent rate.

So far, I have based my implementation on the code found in [this](http://www.idevgames.com/forums/thread-677.html) forum thread (specifically, [this](http://www.idevgames.com/forums/thread-677-post-61768.html#pid61768) post) from quite a while ago (2009).

Digging further through the thread, there is mention of setting up an `NSTimer` for a fixed step interval which would call out to an `update:(NSTimeInterval)duration` method for integrating physics simulations and the like. However, it appears that the delta time between frames is also being calculated in the display link callback method too which i'm finding quite confusing.

I hadn't previously considered a fixed step time interval for updating my scene and to be honest, it doesn't seem quite right to me but i'm still learning OpenGL and the finer nuances of game development.

Is it a good approach to tie the update and render methods together in the display link callback, or would it be better suited to sit elsewhere?

I have used `GLKit` for iOS and to get everything up and working was fairly simple in that you conform to the appropriate delegate methods and your update and render methods are called accordingly.

So far, my code looks like this: (based on the code found in the forum thread)

```
static CVReturn displayLinkOutputCallback(CVDisplayLinkRef displayLink, const CVTimeStamp *now, const CVTimeStamp *outputTime, CVOptionFlags flagsIn, CVOptionFlags *flagsOut, void *displayLinkContext)
{
    NSOpenGLView *view = (__bridge NSOpenGLView *)displayLinkContext;

    NSTimeInterval deltaTime = 1.0 / (outputTime->rateScalar * (double)outputTime->videoTimeScale / (double)outputTime->videoRefreshPeriod);

    [view update:deltaTime];

    [view drawRect:[view frame]];

    return kCVReturnSuccess;
}
```

Is this a viable approach? Should I be using an `NSTimer` instead? Or is there an alternative method that would perhaps be better suited?

I am not overly familiar with `CVDisplayLink` so I am unsure if this is the best place to be implementing methods to update as well as render my scene. Should `CVDisplayLink` be used in this way, i.e.: for scene rendering and updating all in one?

Any further information would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The deltaTime calculation you're using seems to be giving me the FPS value I was looking to calculate.  In fact, by doing `1.00 / deltaTime` (from your calculations) you can get the number of frames per second.  Thanks!

Comment: Based on your comment, does that mean that the `deltaTime` value is actually the frame number and not the time between frames? If so, is there any way to calculate that?

Comment: Delta time is actually the time between frames.  When doing 1.00 / deltaTime, you're dividing a full second by the time between frames - which gives you the amount of frames you get in a second.

Comment: Example: If deltaTime was a steady 0.25 (meaning there's 0.25 seconds between frames), the calculation would be 1.00 / 0.25 = 4.  So this means you're running at 4 frames per second.

Comment: Just to make it clear: your code seems right to me.  It's very similar to the code that I'm using for the same purpose.